# How do I upload to Google Cloud Storage with Curl and an API key?

Tags: http, curl, post, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload to google cloud storage with Curl and an API key, without success.  The error message seems to indicate that I lack the Content-length header, which I don't.  Any ideas?

```
$ curl -v -T ./myfile -X POST https://storage.googleapis.com/my-app/my-bucket/myfile?key=<my-api-token>
> Host: storage.googleapis.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 4
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required
< Date: Thu, 23 Feb 2017 13:46:59 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Server: UploadServer
< Content-Length: 1564
< Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="36,35,34"
< Connection: close
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 411 (Length Required)!!1</title>
  <style>
    [snip snip]
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>411.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>POST requests require a <code>Content-length</code> header.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Closing connection 0
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

API keys do not provide authentication. They associate a call with a project for purposes of quota and a few other things, but you cannot use them to access resources that require anything beyond anonymous access.

What you'll need is an "Access Key", which can be acquired in a variety of ways, usually via an OAuth exchange. If you have the `gcloud` command installed, the easiest way to grab a quick access key to use with cURL is to run `gcloud auth print-access-token`. The following should work:

```
$> curl -v --upload-file my-file.txt \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer `gcloud auth print-access-token`" \ 
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/my-file.txt'
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I get a different error: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Invalid argument.</Message><Details>POST object expects Content-Type multipart/form-data</Details></Error>`

Comment: What curl command are you using now? Looks like you're doing a POST instead of a PUT.

Comment: That was it! I somehow still had `-X POST` in the command.  Thanks.

Comment: I could not get this to work with this URL. Instead I needed to use the form:

`https://{bucket}.storage.googleapis.com/{object}`

Comment: I mean, if we have gcloud to get the auth access token, then it's easier to use gsutil than curl. So... The real problem is that gcloud is a half a gig and I don't want that on my container.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Apr 2023 !!!**

Check this [GCP document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) out!

**TLDR; Follow these steps:**

0. Collect token: use `gcloud auth print-access-token` or do steps 1-6
1. Open [GCP Oauth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground)
2. Select permissions under "Cloud Storage API v1"
3. Click "Authorize APIs"
4. You will be redirect to your GCP account, allow "Google OAuth 2.0 Playground"
5. You will redirect to a page with "Authorization code", clicking  "Exchange authorization code for tokens"
6. Collect the value of "access_token" to use later
7. To upload

```bash
TOKEN="your token from step #0 or #6"
curl -X POST -T /path/to/your/file/big_file.json \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o?uploadType=media&name=big_file.json"
```

**Note 1:** curl which is installed via `snap` may not work: it may say it's unable to read the file. Reinstall curl with `apt install curl`

**Note 2:** if you upload a big file using `--data-binary` like below, curl may crash due to OOM, use `-T` instead. `--data-binary` tries to load the whole file into RAM before sending while `-T` just streams it.

```bash
curl -X POST --data-binary @/path/to/your/file/big_file.json \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
"https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o?uploadType=media&name=big_file.json"
```

8. To download (sometimes you need to mark the object as public)

```bash
(curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
-o "/path/to/download/folder/big_file.json" \
"https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o/big_file.json?alt=media") >/dev/null
```

Note: Use `>/dev/null` to prevent curl from printing out the file content. This is much faster especially when your file is big.